# get made up so i can add and right desc to each page

Tags: reactjs

That's how I'm going to get the right title and description for each page. The way I've done it is by making a file called head.js

It then takes props into title and description.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const Head = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
<title>{props.title}</title>
<meta name="description" content={props.desc}/>
</React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Head;
```

Error on Head:

> Line 1:  'Component' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

But for example, in my Login there, I import the file that has this information. with title and description.

```
class Login extends Component {

<Meta title="Hello test world" desc="Hello test 2"/>
.......
```

Error with "Meta":

> Parsing error: Unexpected token

It's because I do not have the same title on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

For your first error, just change your import statement to `import React from 'react'`, because you're not using the `Component` keyword anywhere in your component so you don't need to import it explicitly.

For your second error, I would need more information on the complete error log and which line it was triggered on, but you can try to create a space before the ending tag on the meta tag like this: `<Meta />`

Comment: Yes I have tried to throw Meta down at the return area and I give those values that I described earlier. Then nothing comes forth.

But, for example, I lay the Meta before `render () {}` area so it's doing the mistake that describes it here: "Parsing error: Unexpected token"

Comment: i have fix this with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-document-meta